# Textarea in AngularJS not rendering HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a textarea in my Ionic's App that is used to create a new message, or to edit a message. My problem is when I try to edit the message, the textarea doesn't render the String as HTML tags.

I've already tried to set `ng-bind-html` and use the `$sce` filter.

Here's a [Plunker with what I've already tried.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlTZwAQTjKjMCuRFoQoa?p=preview)

Comment: You should add your relevant code to the question and make it clear what you would like to happen. The behaviour in the plunkr is exactly what I would expect to happen.

Comment: It's pretty much what @Olezt did here https://plnkr.co/edit/WDvKdG?p=preview

Comment: But with the textarea, and the HTML as Rich Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to bind html in a textarea but you can try "contenteditable"

```
<div ng-bind-html="text_field.text"
     contenteditable="true" 
     ng-model="text_field.text"
     cols="50"
     rows="10">
```

Have a look at this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/WDvKdG?p=preview